Invoke-Command : Register-ScheduledTask : No mapping betwen account names and security IDs was done
I want to create a scheduled task from remote place launched by local system account
I followed instructions from this post but i didn't help (Register-ScheduledTask : No mapping betwen account names and security IDs was done)
# Activation 
Invoke-Command -Credential $admetCREDS -ComputerName $PC.DNSHostName -UseSSL -ScriptBlock {
param($NomUSER, $NomADMIN, $NomPOSTE)
$Actions = (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "cmd" -Argument "/c net user $NomADMIN /active")
# trigger
$Class1 = cimclass MSFT_TaskLogonTrigger Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler
$Trigger1 = $Class1  | New-CimInstance -ClientOnly
$Trigger1.Enabled = $true
$Trigger1.UserId = "Domain\$NomUSER"

$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $NomPOSTE\Système -LogonType ServiceAccount
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Actions -Principal $Principal -Trigger ($Trigger1), ($Trigger2), ($Trigger3)
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Key" -TaskPath \Microsoft\Windows\BitLocker -InputObject $Task
} -ArgumentList ($NomUSER, $NomADMIN, $NomPOSTE)

But i get this error :
Le mappage entre les noms de compte et les ID de sécurité n’a pas été effectué. (24,8):UserId:
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTa    sk], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070534,Register-ScheduledTask
    + PSComputerName        : remotePC.domain.com

I tried with user "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" but it's the same.
From local computer, it works.
Is there a way to make it working with invoke-command? Thanks.

Does New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "SYSTEM" -RunLevel Highest work?

@Mathias R. Jessen : YES it works! thank you very much. You can make the answzr and i will validate it.
